# How do I decrease a height of a div onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-animate

I am using the following to increase the height of a div on click but I need the height to rever to original if the link is clicked again.

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.anchor_clicker').click(function(){
    $('#increaseth_the_height').animate({height:'930'})
})
    });
```

Comment: @hjpotter92 Is that still valid? According to the [documentation for toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) it does not accept those parameters? According to [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing it against the element & toggling based on that. This assumes you only have 1 element with the .anchor_clicker class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.anchor_clicker').click(function(){
    if( $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height') == 930 ) {
      $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height','100');
      $('#increaseth_the_height').animate({height:'100'})
    } else {
      $('.anchor_clicker').data('stored-height','930');
      $('#increaseth_the_height').animate({height:'930'})
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var isExpanded=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.anchor_clicker').click(function(){
    if(isExpanded==false)
    {
         $('#increaseth_the_height').animate({height:'930'})
         isExpanded=true
    } else
    {
         $('#increaseth_the_height').animate({height:'ORIGANAL'})
         isExpanded=false
    }
})
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to remember the "clicked" state and do a `if` to determine whether to shrink or grow the div...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = 0;
    $('.anchor_clicker').click(function(){
        if(clicked === 0){
             $('#increaseth_the_height').animate({height:'930'})
             clicked = 1;
        }
        else {
            $('#increaseth_the_height').animate({height:'300'}) //or whatever the orig height was
            clicked = 0;   
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add one, just to have the efficiency argument in there:

```
$(function(){
    function animateHeight($item,ht,spd){
        $item.stop().animate({height:ht},spd);
    }

    $("#topbar-show").click(function(){
        $(this).toggle(function(){
            animateHeight($(this),40,200);
        },function(){
            animateHeight($(this),10,200);
        });
    });
});
```

I added the `.stop()` method to prevent queuing of animation, and made a function out of the animation, which allows the flexibility to use the animation on as many objects as you like.

If the `.toggle()` function isn't to your liking, you could always use a class instead:

```
$(function(){
    function animateHeight($item,ht,spd){
        $item.stop().animate({height:ht},spd);
    }

    $("#topbar-show").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){            
            $(this).removeClass('clicked');
            animateHeight($(this),10,200);
        } else {                  
            $(this).addClass('clicked');      
            animateHeight($(this),40,200);
        }
    });
});
```

I personally prefer the class method, but to each their own.

Comment: This way of calling toggle() is deprecated as of 1.8 & does not exist in 1.9+ [See here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: yeah i didnt know which version he was using. i added the class-based method, which i also made clear i preferred.